# Set is not removing the duplicates

Tags: c++, set

I am having trouble putting a file of words into a set. I can read the file and the words go into the set but the set doesn't discard the repeated words. Here is the snippet of code that I believe is causing the problem.

```
using namespace std;

while(readText >> line){

     set<string> wordSet;
     wordSet.insert(line);


     for (std::set<std::string>::iterator i = wordSet.begin(); i != wordSet.end(); i++)
        {
        cout << *i << " ";
        }

  }
```

the sample file is this
    1
    2
    2
    3
    4
    5
    5

and the output is exactly the same

Comment: You have your `for` loop that prints inside your `while` loop that is reading and modifying your set

Comment: ...and your `wordSet` definition is inside the `while` loop so it's created (and destroyed) every iteration of the loop.

Comment: Hah! Two bugs which together make the program look like it's *almost* working.

Comment: ... as such, your code is effectively doing the following: `while(readText >> line) { cout << line << " "; }`

Comment: You put exactly one string into a set, and then you print that entire string. The string is not going to break itself up into individual words, entirely on its own volition.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I actually said the same thing, but then I had a thought - doesn't `>>` break on whitespace?

Comment: @MarkRansom: "*doesn't `>>` break on whitespace?*" - yes, it does

Answer (score 4):

As stated in comments, you are not using the `std::set` correctly.  You need to move it, and the `for` loop, outside of your `while` loop:

```
using namespace std;

set<string> wordSet;

while(readText >> line) {
    wordSet.insert(line);
}

for (set<string>::iterator i = wordSet.begin(); i != wordSet.end(); i++) {
    cout << *i << " ";
}
```